# Workbox-webpack-plugin nested urls sw registration

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have nested routes in my react app, like https://my-app.com/someroute/new and on https://my-app.com/someroute level service worker registration works fine, but on https://my-app.com/someroute/new level it fails with

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://my-app.com/someroute/') with script ('https://my-app.com/someroute/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

I've tried to set directoryIndex equal to '../' but also no success.

My workbox-plugin config is here:

```
new GenerateSW({
    cacheId: 'my-app',
    skipWaiting: true,
    clientsClaim: true,
    exclude: [/\.map$/, /^manifest.*\.js(?:on)?$/, /\.html$/],
}),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that when your web app requests the URL `https://my-app.com/someroute/service-worker.js` from your web server, instead of returning the JavaScript contents of `service-worker.js`, it's returning an HTML document. This is presumably a "404 not found" error document, because the web server doesn't think that the `https://my-app.com/someroute/service-worker.js` exists.

The way to resolve this is to ensure that there's a valid `service-worker.js` file that lives in the `/someroute/` directory under your web server's root.

The `GenerateSW` `workbox-webpack-plugin` has a `swDest` property that can be used to control the location that the service work file will be output. Setting it to `swDest: '/someroute/service-worker.js'` might be sufficient to solve your problem.